# Why does [self superview].center not refer to the center?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview

This code:

```
m_networkActivityView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NetworkActivityView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[self addSubview:m_networkActivityView];
m_networkActivityView.center = self.center;
m_networkActivityView.hidden = true;
```

gets me this, which is off center because it's centered on the table, not the screen:

[image]

while this code

```
m_networkActivityView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NetworkActivityView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[self addSubview:m_networkActivityView];
m_networkActivityView.center = [self superview].center;
m_networkActivityView.hidden = true;
```

gets me this:

[image]

which I really don't understand.

Comment: check the class of the super view by logging like : NSLog(@"%@", [[self superview] class]); and see why.. another thing you want it above the navigationcontroller?

Comment: It doesn't have to be above the navigationcontroller. superview is null, so that explains it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the `superview` as recommneded in a comment, and it was `null`, which is why it was showing up in the corner. So I did this to fix it:

```
m_networkActivityView.center = 
    CGPointMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width / 2,
    [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height / 2);
```